# Data Dialog Validation: either empty or validated

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to validate some code in MFC and was wondering how to validate none OR a number between a range i.e.

```
void AddBuilding::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_BUILDINGLATITUDE, m_Latitude);
    DDV_MinMaxFloat(pDX, m_Latitude, -90, 90);

}
```

Any ideas? Thanks lots!
James

Comment: If the range is -90 to 90 wouldn't 0 represent none? Generally these kind of popup message box prompts are less preferable to a static text or less invasive validation approach you make yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To get what you're asking for, you'll probably have to write a custom data validator. MFC [Tech Note 026](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57weza95.aspx) covers how to do this. It also has instructions for how to extend the Class Wizard to use your custom routines without your having to write all the code for it by hand, but I'm not sure if the current versions of VS actually support this or not (given how much that part of VS has changed, I'd tend to guess "not", but I'm not at all sure either way).

Answer (score 1):

```
void AddBuilding::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) 
{ 
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX); 

    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_BUILDINGLATITUDE, m_Latitude); 

    if (pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
    {
      if (m_Latitude.GetLength()>0) // You may want to trim the string first.
      {
        m_fLatitude = _tsof(LPCTSTR(m_Latitude));
          // You probably need a better conversion function, that would tell you if
          // the string isn't a number, such as strtod() or sscanf().

        if (m_fLatitude<-90.0 || m_fLatitude>90.0)
        {
          pDX->PrepareEditCtrl(IDC_BUILDINGLATITUDE);
          AfxMessageBox(_T("Wrong latitude"),...);
          pDX->Fail();
        }
      }
    } 
}
```